# Why Apriori use NaN to calculate in Association rule?

Tags: python, apriori

Why does Apriori use NaN to calculate in Association rule?

How to exclude NaN from Ariori to calculate Association rule with NaN

```
df = pd.read_csv('Online Retail.csv')
display(df.head())

df = df.groupby(['InvoiceNo'])['StockCode'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
display(df.head())

df = df.drop('InvoiceNo', 1)
display(df.head())

#***Split items list and fill none with NaN***
df = df['StockCode'].str.split(',', expand = True)
df = df.fillna(value=np.nan)
display(df.head())
print(df.shape)

records = []
for i in range(1, 25900):
    records.append([str(df.values[i, j]) for j in range(0, 1114)])

association_rules = apriori(records, min_support=0.0045, min_confidence=0.2, min_lift=3, min_length=2)
association_results = list(association_rules)

for i in range(0, len(association_results)):
    print(association_results[i][0])

for item in association_results:
    # first index of the inner list
    # Contains base item and add item
    pair = item[0]
    items = [x for x in pair]
    print("Rule: " + items[0] + " -> " + items[1])

    # second index of the inner list
    print("Support: " + str(item[1]))

    # third index of the list located at 0th
    # of the third index of the inner list

    print("Confidence: " + str(item[2][0][2]))
    print("Lift: " + str(item[2][0][3]))
    print("=====================================")
```

After I finished computing, I got this result with NaN.

Rule: 22917 -> nan
Support: 0.00640951388084482
Confidence: 0.6974789915966386
Lift: 107.52385954381752

Rule: 22917 -> nan
Support: 0.006139233175026063
Confidence: 0.6680672268907563
Lift: 106.80415499533146

Rule: nan -> 22918
Support: 0.006216456233831422
Confidence: 0.676470588235294
Lift: 104.90965128566395

Rule: 22917 -> nan
Support: 0.006177844704428743
Confidence: 0.6639004149377594
Lift: 102.96022063756305

Comment: Please edit your post to describe the steps you followed, and the results you get. Do not just paste a huge image with a colab notebook. We try to help here, not do your homework.

Comment: @IñigoGonzález Sorry, I'm new here. I just edited my step already :) Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in your code is:

```
df = df.fillna(value=np.nan)
```

Don't fill Null values with np.nan it is also giving None values to previous None. Replace them with any other value that you know is of no use. like 0 or negative values.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
if I didn't fill na, it's will give none value, and apriori will use none to calculate the association rules btw.

Comment: Yes i got your point, but you are filling Null values with Np.Nan. np.nan is also Null. Go with any other value like a number or something else.

Comment: Did you mean that I need to use Matrix form with association rule? or I can replace it with 0 in this case. Because I used around 8 Hrs to compute these rules.

Comment: See: ```df = df.fillna(value=np.nan)``` Here you should do ```df = df.fillna(value=0)``` or ```df = df.fillna(value=-1)``` or anyother value. if your null values are 1000 lets suppose. then 1000 are too much to mess up the apriori algorithm. Try this case. Hope this will find you the success.

Comment: I try `df.fillna(value=0)` but 0 still appeared.

Rule: PRD0900239 -> 0
Support: 0.00482910744000277
Confidence: 0.43062114057391937
Lift: 3.140950458605671